# When I upgrade for 14.04 to 16.04 will the changes I made for 14.04 to work on my laptop be lost?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I made changes to some settings so that 14.04 will work on my Dell Inspirion 11. As I recall it was to comment out a couple of lines in a file.  If I could find the reference to what I changed I would not ask this question.  Are all config files over written with the upgrade?

Comment: No, not all of the config files are overwritten during the upgrade. However, the important files that may be replaced usually give you an option to look at the old file vs the new file, and you can decide which one you want to keep. My recommendation is to accept the new file when you can, and reintroduce any changes, if still required, to the new file.

Answer (score 1):

Config files tend to be overwritten if an overwrite is needed (i.e. a new config format version), and if the current config file is reported as altered.

If this is the case, `apt` will prompt you to decide whether to keep the old file or replace it. Your prompt will look something like this:

```
Configuration file `/opt/application/conf/XXX.conf'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ? Your options are:

Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : background this process to examine the situation
```

From there on out, the choice is completely yours. Apt will not overwrite files unless they're unchanged without asking you first.